# InputFile Loops Handling Two data

Tags: python

So I am trying to find the best two candidates from the file "data.txt" and then print out the name of the candidate and their score. The best candidate is the one whose score is the smallest, so negative numbers count. The file looks like this:

- Harry
- 100
- Kim
- 40
- Mac
- 79
- Hudson
- -150

The best two candidates are Kim and Hudson. So the program should print out:

> Kim
>
> 40
>
> Hudson
>
> -150

Here is the code I have so far:

```
name = infile.readline()

score = float(infile.readline())

name2 = infile.readline()
score2 = float(infile.readline())

bestCandidate = name
bestScore = score
bestCandidate2 = name2
bestScore2 = score2


while name != "":
    name = infile.readline()
    if name != "":
        score = float(infile.readline())
        if score < bestScore:
            bestCandidate = name
            bestScore = score
        if bestScore < bestScore2:
            bestCandidate = name
            bestScore2 = score

print(bestCandidate)
print(bestScore)
print(bestCandidate2)
print(bestScore2)


infile.close()
```

Instead of printing out the best two, the file prints the following:

> Hudson
>
> -150
>
> Kim
>
> -150

Comment: The problem lies in your second condition, `if bestScore < bestScore2`. You might consider a different approach, though: read all names and scores, store them in a mapping, sort keyed on score, take the first two. That's theoretically slower -- O(N log N) vs. the O(N) approach you're trying, but it doesn't matter much if N isn't big and is more flexible if you ever want to do anything other than grab the best two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a `continue` so that you don't update bestScore2. The `continue` statement skips the rest of the loop and goes to executing the `while` statement again.

```
 infile = open('d.txt')
name = infile.readline()

score = float(infile.readline())

bestCandidate = name
bestScore = score
name2 = infile.readline()

score2 = float(infile.readline())

bestCandidate2 = name2
bestScore2 = score2

#exchange bestScore2 and bestScore if bestScore2 < bestScore
if bestScore2 < bestScore:
    bestScore, bestScore2 = bestScore2, bestScore
    bestCandidate, bestCandidate2 = bestCandidate2, bestCandidate


while name != "":
    name = infile.readline()
    if name != "":
        score = float(infile.readline())
        if score < bestScore:
            bestCandidate2, bestScore2 = bestCandidate, bestScore
            bestCandidate = name
            bestScore = score
            continue
        elif score > bestScore and score < bestScore2:
            bestCandidate2, bestScore2 = name, score



print(bestCandidate)
print(bestScore)
print(bestCandidate2)
print(bestScore2)


infile.close()
```

So the output becomes:

```
Hudson

-150.0
Kim

40.0
```

Here is a better way using [heapq](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html). Heaps have the property that they maintain an order. Here you want to maintain the order of scores, so you are storing a tuple of (score, name) in the heap. So, if you pop the heap twice, you get the two best candidates.

```
import heapq

h = []
infile = open('input_data.txt')
name = infile.readline()

score = float(infile.readline())
heapq.heappush(h, (score, name))

while name != "":
    name = infile.readline()
    if name != "":
        score = float(infile.readline())
        heapq.heappush(h, (score, name))

infile.close()
bestScore, bestCandidate = heapq.heappop(h)
bestScore2, bestCandidate2 = heapq.heappop(h)

print(bestCandidate)
print(bestScore)
print(bestCandidate2)
print(bestScore2)
```

Comment: Is there another way without using continue?

Comment: The first version is just broken (consider a sequence of scores like 2, 10, 1). Also the use of `heapq` for two elements is IMO overkilling and that's not the way to use an heap anyway (you normally don't add **all** elements to the heap but instead you keep the heap big enough to contain only the first n elements you are interested in, using `heappop` in the loop).

Answer (score 1):

A better way to implement this is

1. initialize the two candidates to "sentinel" values
2. loop over the elements
3. if an element is better than best candidate (or the best is empty) copy it to second and update best candidate
4. **else** if the element is better than the second best candidate (or the second is empty) update it

The important part is that if you find `x < best` you need to do two operations: `second_best = best` and `best = x` to avoid losing the old smallest value that should become the second smallest.

In code:

```
...
best = None
second_best = None
while True:
    name = f.readline()
    if not name: break
    score = f.readline()
    if not score: break
    score = float(score)
    if best is None or score < best[1]:
        second_best = best # This is the important point
        best = (name, score)
    elif second_best is None or score < second_best[1]:
        second_best = (name, score)
...
```

If you forget the step of moving `best` in `second_best` the program won't work for sequences like (2, 10, 1) because the answer will be (1, 10) instead of (1, 2).